# Map RLMObject from array and not dictionary with Realm-JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I have a data structure that looks like following:

[image]

I'm trying to map it. I will have array of DayChoice objects.
Each of them contains `index` and `string` properties.

Now I face trouble with writing mapping, usually it goes like this:

[image]

But as you can see my DayChoice objects do not have keys, and are in arrays. How do I write mapping for this?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this, this seems to have been resolved in [Realm-JSON #88](https://github.com/matthewcheok/Realm-JSON/issues/88).